# Life management of std::function/std::bind (passing a functor as lparam in Windows PostMessage)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, c++11

This only seems like a Windows question, but the essence of my question is really a C++11 (or MS C++0x TR1). It is about passing `std::function` objects and their life cycle.

I want to have a generic framework for asynchronous execution via Windows `PostMessage` API. This is when circumstances forces me to exit from the current message handling and register the task in the message queue.

The framework is working fine with pointers to static function (in `WPARAM`) and pointer to context (in `LPARAM`) which contains a 'this' pointer as well as other context.

I want to take it to next level and using the bind and function structure. I'm on Visual Studio 2010 (i.e. `std::function` exists but TR1).

So far this is what I've:

I'm registering the `WM_ASYNC_TASK` a by the text book, and my windows procedure (I'm actually using WTL) is working fine. `PostMessage` works fine, and message will eventually reach `onAsyncTask` with `wparam` and `lparam`, correctly and as expected.

```
const UINT WM_ASYNC_TASK = RegisterWindowMessage(L"Async-Task");
```

I've a `CPlugin`, which is where I want to send the send the task. I've `CHiddenWindow` which is the Window implementation that gets the message. I would like the `onAsyncTask` to forward the function back to `CPlugin`. `hwnd` is a handle to the window.

In `CPlugin` I've:

```
void CPlugin::ShowMessageBox( void* arg ) {
    wchar_t* text = (wchar_t*)arg;
    MessageBox( NULL, text, L"Title", MB_OK )
}

void CPlugin::Sender( ) {
    std::function<void(void*)> f = std::bind( &CPlug::ShowMessagebox, 
                                              this, 
                                              std::placeholders::_1 );
    PostMessage( hwnd, WM_ASYNC_TASK, (WPARAM)f, (LPARAM)"Hello!!" );
}
```

In CHiddenWindow at the handler of WM_ASYNC_TASK message I've:

```
void CHiddinWindow::onAsyncTask( WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam, /* more arguments */ )
{
    std::function<void(void*)> f = (std::function<void(void*)>)wparam;
    void* arg = lparam;
    f( arg );
}
```

**Questions**:

1. Currently, the compiler complains when I'm trying to cast f to WPARAM, within `PostMessage` (`WPARAM` is basically a long).
2. I'm OK if I'm taking the address of `f`: `(WPARAM)&f`.
3. Which raise another question about the life cycle of f. How do I keep it?
4. When passing `&f` (keeping `f` outside `Sender()` - not my desire), I'm getting access violation in `onAsyncHandler`, when trying to dereference `f`.
5. About the life cycle, can I put f under the control of `std::shared_ptr` somehow?
6. There is no real reason to pass the argument to my function (in my case - the text) in wparam. I think there should be a way to have the text part of the `std::function` object, but fail with the syntax.

As I said, I'm on VS 2010 before variadic templates. Microsoft has TR1 implementation of C++0x. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't include boost as it isn't available for me right now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Compiler is correct, `std::function` is non-trivial object that could not be casted to `WPARAM` which is actually `unsigned int`.
2. Yes, this is possible (and actually the single correct way) but raises correct type casting and life time management problems.
3. Life time of `f` definitely shall be managed by `CPlugin`. It's closely related to `CPlugin` life time as you bind it to `this` and `CPlugin` member function.
4. Of course, that's because `f` is destroyed when goes out of scope of `Sender()` function (when it returns). And due to asynchronous messaging this happens before `CHiddenWindow` processes the message. In `CHiddenWindow::onAsyncTask` pointer to `f` is already invalid.
5. `shared_ptr` is good tool to enforce shared ownership (which is your case) but you still cannot pass it via `WPARAM`.
6. What is wrong with `std::bind(&CPlugin::ShowMessagebox, this, "Hello!")`;?

Possible solution for such framework:

1. Create global async task queue, `CPlugin` and `CHiddenWindow` shall have access to it
2. Each task in queue shall have unique identifier, e.g. count-through number
3. `CPlugin::Sender()` places task into queue and posts async message to `CHiddenWindow` with task ID as `WPARAM/LPARAM`. `Sender()` also keeps this task ID in `CPlugin` instance - it shall be removed from queue in case when `CPlugin` instance gets destroyed before peer processed all messages.
4. `CHiddenWindow::onAsyncTask` gets task ID, searches for corresponding task in queue and runs the task functor if task was found. Then it removes task from queue.

Of course, you could use some simple (and wrong) solution, like:

```
typedef std::function<void(void*)> Func;

void CPlugin::Sender()
{
    Func* f = new Func(std::bind(&CPlugin::ShowMessagebox, this, "Hello!"));
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_ASYNC_TASK, (WPARAM)f, 0);
}

void CHiddenWindow::onAsyncTask(WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    Func* f = (Func*)wparam;
    (*f)();
    delete f;
}
```

But this solution has two flaws:

1. What if posted message will be never processed by receiver, e.g. it will be closed for some reason? In this case `Func` object will be leaked wasting your memory.
2. What if `CPlugin` instance that sent the message gets destroyed before receiver processes the message? In this case you will have Undefined Behavior (very probably access violation/crash) on calling `f()` inside `CHiddenWindow::onAsyncTask`.

So you shall consider such solution only in case when you have strong guarantee that all posted messages will be processed by receivers and senders will not be destroyed before all posted messages are processed.